# Why Apex Exceptions Email Settings are not copied to Sandbox upon sandbox refresh?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, sandboxpostcopy

Why Apex Exceptions Email Settings are not copied to Sandbox upon sandbox refresh?

We need to manually setup Apex Exceptions Email Settings every time after sandbox refresh.
Is there any way to make this automatic, probably by using SandboxPostCopy interface or by other means?

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard object `ApexEmailNotification` which stores information about `Apex Exceptions Email Settings`

It is possible to retrieve these data using SOQL or Tooling API SOQL

```
SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Email,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,SystemModstamp,UserId FROM ApexEmailNotification
```

[image]

Despite this object is defined as EverCreateable, it is not possible to use Apex to create this records, if you try to

```
insert new ApexEmailNotification(UserId='0051t000002So5jAAC');
```

you will receive an error

> DML operation Insert not allowed on ApexEmailNotification

[image]

Even though DML operation Insert is forbidden on this object, there is still an option to use Tooling API POST method to create this records by sending JSON body to `/services/data/v45.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexEmailNotification` endpoint

[image]

or even using usual endpoint

`/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ApexEmailNotification`

[image]

So basically it is possible to write a script in SandboxPostCopy which would query production data and use self callout to insert them in Sandbox after refresh.